# Winload.efi missing on RAID HDD

Tags: raid, windows-8.1

We have a workstation running Windows 8.1. At system start the error "winload.efi" missing occurs.

Now I wanted to drive a system repair. The problem is that the hard disk is hanging in a software RAID, so I can't work with a repair disk. 
As soon as I display the hard disks with `diskpart`, the list is empty.
If I deactivate the software RAID, I find the disk, but `chkdsk` identifies all data as faulty.

Are there any options I can do without a complete reinstallation?